# How to show validation error message in the angular form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular15

I am trying to show validation error message for angular for. I have three checkboxes. If i not selected anyone i want to show error message. How to do it in reactive form validation in angular.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-ddqhne?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html:

```
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <label *ngFor="let val of data"><input type="checkbox" name="val.name" id="val.id" formControlName="cb"> {{val.value}}</label>
    <div style="color: red; padding-top: 0.2rem">
        Atleast select one checkbox
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        cb: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
     });
  }
```

Comment: The accepted solution, after check the stackblitz return an  array with the elements are not in the same kind. (add in .html `<pre>formGroup?.value|json</pre>) Really it's a very, very, very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer to use `formControlName` the remaining explanation stays the same! But I use `.bind(this, data)` to pass the data that is used on the `*ngFor` to initialize the checkboxes, because the data is dynamic, so we need to pass the original data to ensure the values are checked so that atleast once checkbox is checked!

validator

```
export function ValidateCheckboxes(data: any, control: AbstractControl) {
  console.log(data, control.value.cb);
  if (
    !data.some(
      (item: any, index: number) => control.value.cb[index][item.id]
    )
  ) {
    return { checkboxSectionValid: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-tnvosj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

We can use a `formArray` for the checkboxes this will ensure the inputs are under the same formArray control

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  cb: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
const cb: FormArray = this.cbArray;
this.data.forEach((item: any) => {
  cb.push(new FormControl(null));
});
```

We need a custom validator to check if any of the checkboxes are checked, we use the below code for that

```
this.formGroup.setValidators(ValidateCheckboxes);
```

validator function

```
export function ValidateCheckboxes(control: AbstractControl) {
  console.log(control.value.cb);
  if (!control.value.cb.some((item: any) => item)) {
    return { checkboxSectionValid: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

On the html side, we group all the checkboxes under one `formGroupName`, then assign the formArray controls to the checkboxes. Then we can check if the error exists by doing `*ngIf="formGroup?.errors?.checkboxSectionValid"` on the error message div!

```
<div formArrayName="cb">
  <label *ngFor="let val of cbArray.controls; let i = index"
    ><input
      type="checkbox"
      name="{{ val.name }}"
      id="{{ val.id }}"
      [formControl]="val"
    />
    {{ data[i].value }}</label
  >
</div>
<div
  style="color: red; padding-top: 0.2rem"
  *ngIf="formGroup?.errors?.checkboxSectionValid"
>
  Atleast select one checkbox
</div>
```

full code

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateCheckboxes(control: AbstractControl) {
  console.log(control.value.cb);
  if (!control.value.cb.some((item: any) => item)) {
    return { checkboxSectionValid: true };
  }
  return null;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  public data = [
    {
      name: 'chk1',
      id: 'chk1',
      value: 'Car',
    },
    {
      name: 'chk2',
      id: 'chk2',
      value: 'Bus',
    },
    {
      name: 'chk3',
      id: 'chk4',
      value: 'Motor',
    },
  ];

  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  get cbArray() {
    return this.formGroup.get('cb') as FormArray;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      cb: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    });
    const cb: FormArray = this.cbArray;
    this.data.forEach((item: any) => {
      cb.push(new FormControl(null));
    });
    this.formGroup.setValidators(ValidateCheckboxes);
  }
}
```

html

```
<div style="padding: 1rem">
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="cb">
      <label *ngFor="let val of cbArray.controls; let i = index"
        ><input
          type="checkbox"
          name="{{ val.name }}"
          id="{{ val.id }}"
          [formControl]="val"
        />
        {{ data[i].value }}</label
      >
    </div>
    <div
      style="color: red; padding-top: 0.2rem"
      *ngIf="formGroup?.errors?.checkboxSectionValid"
    >
      Atleast select one checkbox
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-rqsypy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Any other simple way?

Comment: We can make a custom control validator only over the FormArray and we can indicate the validator when we create the formGroup, it's unnecesary make a setValidator

Comment: @sarann depends, is `data` array variable? or fixed?

Comment: Data is variable

Comment: @sarann Then I would recommend this approach! its dynamic and gets the job done!

Comment: This is look like more code.

Comment: @sarann ok no issues, all the best!

Comment: If it is fixed. How you can write it?

Comment: Already someone written the code for these checkbox. So, I can not touch that code. I have only formcontrolname. So, Using the formcontrolname how can i check it?

Comment: Now i can use only the formcontrolname. So, How to do it?

Comment: @sarann its better you create a new question where you explicitly tell the stack overflow users the constraints you have to solve this problem, what can and cannot be changed on the code, if possible a stackblitz where the issues happens, only then can someone quickly help you, it seems like we are running in loops due to unclear requirements!

Comment: Nice! But this is not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-dhtfwh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @sarann updated my answer [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-tnvosj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Name and id values are same. In this case not working:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-9kmchr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @sarann I can only guide you to a solution, please take the effort and try to take the code to the finish line, by understanding the code, let me know if you have any doubts!

Comment: Name and Id are same value. In this case your code is not working:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-hjj2gx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: How to change this lin:  (item: any, index: number) => item[`chk${index + 1}`]

Comment: @sarann  please check my updated answer, I changed the logic so that its more dynamic [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-tnvosj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

When i try the code you posted I get it to work, as down below (note i changed the name from formGroup to myForm:

app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       cb: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
 }
```

app.component.html

```
  <div style="padding: 1rem">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <label *ngFor="let val of data"
      ><input
        type="checkbox"
        name="val.name"
        id="val.id"
        formControlName="cb"
      />
      {{ val.value }}</label
    >
    <div *ngIf="!myForm?.valid" style="color: red; padding-top: 0.2rem">
      Atleast select one checkbox
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm?.valid">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When no checkbox is checked the submit-button is disabled.
Or is it something else you cant get to work?

*** Edit
Added `*ngIf="!myForm?.valid"` to error message so it shows and hides depending if you have checkbox checked. You can also listen if the form has been touched before to hide the message initially but i leave that as training for you.

Comment: Do not disable button. Can you add ngIf for the error message div ?

Comment: Why cant you do it? Just use the myForm.valid to hide or show the div explaining the message!

Comment: I do not know how to add it. That is my question also

Comment: Sorry didnt see that, i added the code for that aswell.

Comment: Check the Naren Murali answer

Comment: What about it? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
export function AtLeastOne(control: AbstractControl) {
  return control.value.find((x:any)=>x)?null:{error:'at least one'}
}

this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      cb: this.formBuilder.array([],AtLeastOne),
    });
```

We can show the error in the way

```
<div style="color: red; padding-top: 0.2rem"
  *ngIf="formGroup.get('cb')?.errors"
>
  At least select one checkbox
</div>
```

But it's so boried...

Better we can use .css

Imagine you use some like

```
.error{
  color:red;
  display:none;
}
div[formArrayName].ng-invalid.ng-touched ~.error,
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched ~.error,
form.ng-submitted div[formArrayName].ng-invalid ~.error
{
  display:block;
}
```

We can use, with the new @for anf @if

```
@if(formGroup) {
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="cb">
      @for(control of cbArray.controls;let i=$index;track i) {
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="{{ data[i].name }}"
          id="{{ data[i].id }}"
          [formControlName]="i"
        />
        {{ data[i].value }}
      </label>
      }
    </div>
    <div class="error">At least select one checkbox</div>
    <div>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
}
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-afp7wh?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)